# How to use SignalR with non-UI-based clients?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, signalr-hub

In a previous solution, I recall setting up code-behind-type hub connections for unit testing.  I believe I used code from the [previous **SignalR Hubs C# Client** GitHub wiki](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs).

In the [SignalR Hubs API guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) there is an example of using a console-based client:

```
stockTickerHubProxyProxy.On("Notify", () => Console.WriteLine("Notified!"));
```

In an upcoming application there will be notifications to be pushed to several clients.  Some of these clients will be UI-based (JS), and others, will be some back-end code that will perform some task.

I am familiar with the JS-based client connectivity.  My question centers around attaching code-behind-type clients, and how their methods "notified".

I understand that with a UI-based client, the mechanism is to push the update to the client through dynamic invocations to client-side "methods".  Since it's been a few months since I've touched SignalR, what is the best way to accomplish this where there is no UI involved?

To verify that I am understanding the documentation correctly , when [valid transport method](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#transport) is used, a [C#-based (non UI/JS) client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callclient) is notified (push) through the SignalR framework - no client polling required?

Comment: I know the project your speaking of, is the feature your looking for more like *Group Notifications*.  Where a piece of data is broadcasted to all clients?  Then what the client obviously does with the data will be up to your implementation.  Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Basically, yes.  I have not thought about organizing the clients into groups, however, this is a nice level of abstraction (if necessary). Let's say that from a UI, I update an object property.  All other UI clients will be notified by an updateWidget() call from the hub.  Instead of having some polling type listener checking some updated db field, I want to have a code-behind type client that does something when that update is performed.

Comment: Are you seeking something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404662/SignalR-Group-Notifications

Comment: @Greg - It looks like that example uses a UI-based group notification mechanism through JavaScript.  What I'm looking for is a C#-based client that does something with the notification.  I updated the beginning of the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential mechanism is the same for JS and `C#` clients. The solution is exactly what you mentioned in your question. The 'On' method will subscribe the client to any "notify event" triggered by the server. You can refer to the documentation to get a better understanding:
http://www.asp.net/signalr